# How to store a Matlab structure in a Java Hashtable and retrieve it

Tags: java, matlab, struct, hashtable

I want to store a Matlab structure (as defined by `struct`) in an instance of java.util.Hashtable. (If using a different Java hash table class makes this problem easier, I would be interested to hear about that.) However, when I try the obvious `h.put("foo", mystruct)`, where `h` is the java.util.Hashtable and `mystruct` is a Matlab structure, I get an error:

```
'put' requires one of the following:
  MATLAB Compiler SDK
  MATLAB Production Server
  Parallel Computing Toolbox
```

I want this to work without installing additional toolboxes, so I am looking for a different solution.

Is there a way to make a string out of a structure, such that the string can be stored in the Hashtable, and then the structure reconstituted from the string upon retrieval? I suppose that implies being able to unparse and parse structures to/from strings. Is that possible? Does someone see another way of constructing a storable/retrievable representation of a structure?

It looks like it would be possible to represent the structure as a Hashtable itself, and then put a reference to that into the other Hashtable. Upon retrieval it would be necessary to iterate through the keys to rebuild the structure. It seems straightforward but somewhat clumsy and painful. I guess that can be a fall-back option.

Comment: Save the structure to a .mat file and read the mat file as an array of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to get Matlab to reconstitute the structure from a byte array? Aside from writing the byte array to a file and then reading that.

Comment: I don't know. But instead of writing the struct to a mat file you can simply place the struct into a cell array and insert the index of the array into the hash table.

Comment: Another option is using [dictionary](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/dictionary.html) instead of java hash table.

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid Matlab dictionaries, since I ran into other limitations there. I suppose I might end up there again.

Comment: Can you say more about what problems you had with `dictionary`? That should be the way to go. There's also the older `containers.Map`... (that was intended to be superseded by `dictionary`).

Comment: `dictionary` seems to assume all stored values will be the same type; I get an error when I try to store a second value which is not the same type as the first, at any rate. I need to be able to store values of different types.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which I eventually arrived at is to encode the Matlab structure as a string via `jsonencode`, and then decode it via `jsondecode`. I.e.,

```
foo.a = 123;
foo.b = "Hello";
h = java.util.Hashtable ();
h.put ("foo", jsonencode (foo));
foo_reconstituted = jsondecode (h.get ("foo"));
```

This has deficiencies (can't handle Java objects which are values in the structure, and doesn't remember if 1-dimensional arrays are rows or columns) but it's enough for me to keep going.